# Spark 2.4 - dataframe write into s3 bucket

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

From my local PC , i tried to load my DF into S3.. below are my code snippet.

```
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", Util.AWS_ACCESS_KEY)
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", Util.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
  empTableDF.coalesce(1).write
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)      
  .save("s3a://welpocstg/")
```

While running i am getting below exception

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
```

my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Any soultion team

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with below change.

```
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", Util.AWS_ACCESS_KEY)
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", Util.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

  Seq("1","2","3").toDF("id")
  .coalesce(1)
  .write
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)      
  .save("s3a://welpocstg/")
```

Comment: well, there's an entire document dedicated to troubleshooting the s3a connector https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html

Comment: That link doesn't even contain the message "Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain". So clearly irrelevant